# Passing data between views isn't working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I've done this many times with code that is *exactly* the same, but for some reason it isn't working today.

```
 ExampleViewController1 *exampleView = [[ExampleViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExampleViewController1" bundle:nil];
 [exampleView setProjectName:[[self.projectListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
 NSLog(@"%@", [[self.projectListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]);
 XAppDelegate.stackController pushViewController:exampleView fromViewController:nil animated:YES]
```

My `NSLog` prints out appropriately.

`My ExampleViewController1.h` file declared like:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *projectName;
```

I then do this code in `ExampleViewController1.m`'s

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
     NSLog(@"%@", self.projectName);
     self.projectNameLabel.text = self.projectName;
     [super viewDidLoad];
 }
```

The results of my `NSLog`s are curious. The `NSLog` from my `viewDidLoad` appears to be getting called before my other one:

```
 2012-04-22 10:59:41.462 StackedViewKit[43799:f803] (null)
 2012-04-22 10:59:41.463 StackedViewKit[43799:f803] NewTest
```

I have confirmed that the `(null)` value there is from `NSLog(@"%@", self.projectName);`, but that should be the second `NSLog` called...I can't figure out why it is coming through first.

Someone requested this code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
   if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {

    // random color
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)rand())/RAND_MAX green:((float)rand())/RAND_MAX blue:((float)rand())/RAND_MAX alpha:1.0];
   }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: i think u r doing mistake in pushing  XAppDelegate.stackController pushViewController:exampleView fromViewController:nil animated:YES]

Comment: I think there is a better way to get data between views. Try a temp NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I'm using a pre-built UI [PSStackedView](https://github.com/steipete/PSStackedView). This is the way it adds/removes things to the custom "Navigation" controller.

Comment: It must an issue with viewDidLoad. I changed the code to directly set the label's text with: `exampleView.projectNameLabel.text = [[self.projectListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];` and that worked. Strange.

Comment: please check the pushing between the view controllers, i think this is the reason data is not passing between them

Comment: Can you post your code of `initWithNibName:bundle:` in `ExampleViewController1`? Did you call `self.view` inside of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I expected, the problem is that you are trying to access `self.view` inside the initialization method. So move the line `self.view.backgroundColor = ...` to the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.projectName);
    self.projectNameLabel.text = self.projectName;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)rand())/RAND_MAX green:((float)rand())/RAND_MAX blue:((float)rand())/RAND_MAX alpha:1.0];
}
```

---

In fact, the documentation of the [`view`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW2) property says:

> If you access this property and its value is currently nil, the view controller automatically calls the loadView method and returns the resulting view.

So when you call `self.view` in the initialization method, the view controller will have to load the view (from the nib or using the `loadView` method). And that's why `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: @sch yes you are right, i did not notice that. One up vote from me.

Answer (score 2):

> viewDidLoad is called before a view controller is displayed for the
>   first time, not immediately after initWithNibName.
>
> **> viewDidLoad method is called after the view controller has loaded its view
>   hierarchy into memory. This method is called regardless of whether the
>   view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically
>   in the loadView method.**
>
> **> initWithNibName The nib file you specify is not loaded right away. It
>   is loaded the first time the view controller’s view is accessed. If
>   you want to perform additional initialization after the nib file is
>   loaded, override the viewDidLoad method and perform your tasks there.**

**You can use App delegate to pass the data from one to another, that is another alternate solution.**

```
you do in initWithNibName method itself. or in viewDidAppear.
```

Your initWithNibName method should be like this as per as **@sch** comments;

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil { 

     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil] //just set it here first and then check

     if (self) { 
         // do something here; 
         } 
return self; 
}
```

We just need to be smart enough to think about what do we need to in constructor and what do we need to at viewDidLoad (once it had loaded into memory)

Comment: alternatively you may customize the costructor and pass you by this value.

Comment: I am not sure your answer is relevant here. OP says he gets the `NSLog` in `viewDidLoad` before the one after setting the value of the property. That means that in his case, `viewDidLoad` was called immediately after `initWithNibName`. He says: *"but that should be the second NSLog called...I can't figure out why it is coming through first."*.

Comment: Both NSLogs are being called, that's the part I don't understand. I was able to resolve the issue by overriding the synthesized setters and doing everything I wanted to do in the setter.

Comment: Why can not you do in initWithNibName method itself. or in viewDidAppear.

Comment: I will try those options later and report back. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: @user1260375 - The code in your question is correct and is the appropriate way to do this. So you should keep it and figure out why `viewDidLoad` was called immediately after `initWithNibName`. Can you post your code of `initWithNibName`?

Comment: @Praveen-K - You should not access the `view` property inside the initialization method and the line `self.view.backgroundColor = ...` should be in the method `viewDidLoad`. Se my answer for more information.

Comment: @sch ohh yes, you are right. i just edit my answer two seconds before and wrote the statement at the very end of my question